# How can I get the value of a localStorage array item using a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a few localStorage keys that look something like this in dev tools -> storage...

```
panel_1 {"name":"test_name", "item_1":"test_item", "link_1":"test_link"})
```

...each panel I have has multiple items and links with a number in its name that increases. I am trying to go through each panel and for the panel I want to get the first item and link to display on a web page then keep looping through until there's no more items or links before doing the same with the next panel. At the moment when I try this it says "undefined". How can I get the correct value? Right now my code looks like this...

```
var total_keys = localStorage.length;
var panels = [];
var key;
var location = $('#panels .wrapper article:first-child()');

for($i = 0; $i < total_keys; $i++) {
    key = localStorage.key($i);
    if(key.slice(0, 6) === 'panel_') {
        panels.push(key);
    };
};

var total_panels = panels.length;

for(var $i = 0; $i < total_panels; $i++) {
    var panel = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(panels[$i]));
    var items = function() {
        for(var $x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
            var item = 'item_'+$x;
            alert(panel.item);
        };
    };

    location.after(items);
};
```

Comment: `localStorage.key($i);` <-- what is "key"?  I can't recall any `key` prototype in the localStorage API.

Comment: @briosheje https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key

Comment: @Utkanos Oh, thanks. Never ever seen that before, it's not even mentioned in the API examples. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Why is `items` a function?

Comment: @adiga because it's used as a callback in `.after` over `location`, which is a jQuery selector. (https://api.jquery.com/after/). The issue is just that `alert(panel.item);` is undefined, it should rather be `alert(panel[item]);`

Comment: @briosheje ah, I only checked the first part of the documentation which said the parameter could be *htmlString or Element or Text or Array or jQuery*

Comment: @adiga yep, that's a "weird" approach, I'm just wondering if panel works properly in that function callback, but it should.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `panel[item]` instead of `panel.item` (which means `panel["items"]`). It would explain the "undefined" value.

The most inner loop should look like

```
for(var $x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    var item = 'item_'+$x;
    alert(panel[item]);
};
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use the comments system for that.

Comment: To be fair, your comment actually hints at the correct answer - it's just your wordering sounds more like a request for clarification. Downvote retracted.